# Create check constraint for DataRange with flexible lower bound. Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which DDL is specified bellow.

This table has a field called  `translation_years` (`daterange`), and I would like to create check constraint that would provide following logic:

-stored range should be fully lower than specified range(`<<`)with open upper bound(infinit)

-lower bound of this restriction range should be calculated on each check. It should be first January of the year after following year.   For example for now it would be `1.1.2022`.

What I did:

Since I am not good in Postgres, only one thing that I figured out is:

```
alter table archives_tvseriesmodel
add CONSTRAINT defend_future_check check (translation_years << daterange(lower bound time here::date, NULL::date, '()'::text))
```

Instead of  `lower bound time here` it lacked some function that would calculate 1.1.2022 until the end of the current year, and  1.1.2023 for the next year, etc on each entry(or year change if it is possible).

Is it possible to implement such thing in Postgres or it is just a pure utopia?

Thanks.

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table archives_tvseriesmodel
(
    id                serial       not null
        constraint archives_tvseriesmodel_pkey
            primary key,
    name              varchar(50)  not null
        constraint archives_tvseriesmodel_series_name_4e81420d_uniq
            unique,
    imdb_url          varchar(200) not null
        constraint archives_tvseriesmodel_imdb_url_80c51b99_uniq
            unique
        constraint url_to_imdb_check
            check (upper((imdb_url)::text) ~~ upper('%www.imdb.com%'::text)),
    entry_author_id   integer      not null
        constraint archives_tvseriesmod_entry_author_id_69743563_fk_users_use
            references users_user
            deferrable initially deferred,
    is_finished       boolean      not null,
    rating            smallint
        constraint rating_from_1_to_10
            check (((rating >= 1) AND (rating <= 10)) OR (rating IS NULL))
        constraint archives_tvseriesmodel_rating_f49922bf_check
            check (rating >= 0),
    translation_years daterange    not null
        constraint no_medieval_cinema_check
            check (translation_years >> daterange(NULL::date, '1896-01-06'::date, '()'::text))
);

alter table archives_tvseriesmodel
    owner to postgres;

create index archives_tvseriesmodel_entry_author_id_69743563
    on archives_tvseriesmodel (entry_author_id);

create index archives_tvseriesmodel_imdb_url_80c51b99_like
    on archives_tvseriesmodel (imdb_url);

create index archives_tvseriesmodel_series_name_4e81420d_like
    on archives_tvseriesmodel (name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
=# select date_trunc('year', now() at time zone 'utc') + interval '2 years' as lower_bound;
     lower_bound     
---------------------
 2022-01-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

The constraint definition should be:

```
alter table archives_tvseriesmodel
  add CONSTRAINT defend_future_check 
    check (
      translation_years << 
        daterange(
          (date_trunc('year', current_date) + interval '2 years')::date, 
          NULL::date, 
          '()'::text
        )
    )
;
```

Comment: Mike, thank you for the help. SELCT works correctly but it says : [0A000] Can't use subqueries in check constraints. Could you please specify full DDL on constraint creation? Maybe i got wrong somewhere.

Comment: @AlekseiKhatkevich, You don't need the `select` part or the alias.  Just use this part as the expression:  `date_trunc('year', current_date) + interval '2 years'` in your `create table`.  I will update my answer.